# Is it possible to remove the .php ending in apache without to add a /?

Tags: php, apache

I want that instead of example.com/example.php or example.com/example/ that example.com/example is in the url, is there any way to do this in apache?

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But that add a slash instead of .php

Comment: This might help you a bit, check [ServerFault Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1085093/why-the-redirection-in-htaccess-not-work)